# Machine vision in Python

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision

I would like to perform a few basic machine vision tasks using Python and I'd like to know where I could find tutorials to help me get started.

As far as I know, the only free library for Python that does machine vision is [PyCV](http://pycv.sharkdolphin.com/) (which is a wrapper for [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) apparently), but I can't find any appropriate tutorials.

My main tasks are to acquire an image from FireWire. Segment the image in different regions. And then perform statistics on each regions to determine pixel area and center of mass.

Previously, I've used Matlab's [Image Processing Tootlbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) without any problems. The functions I would like to find an equivalent in Python are [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and [gray2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gray2ind.html).

Thanks!

Comment: Python-bindings for OpenCV are included in the [official distribution](http://opencv.org/). You might also be interested in [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/) a python framework built on top of several other libraries including OpenCV

Answer (score 13):

OpenCV is probably your best bet for a library; you have your choice of wrappers for them. I looked at the SWIG wrapper that comes with the standard OpenCV install, but ended up using [ctypes-opencv](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/) because the memory management seemed cleaner.

They are both very thin wrappers around the C code, so any C references you can find will be applicable to the Python.

OpenCV is huge and not especially well documented, but there are some decent samples included in the samples directory that you can use to get started. A searchable OpenCV API reference is [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/).

You didn't mention if you were looking for online or print sources, but I have the [O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130/) book and it's quite good (examples in C, but easily translatable).

The [FindContours](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/ref/OpenCVRef_Cv.htm#decl_cvFindContours) function is a bit similar to regionprops; it will get you a list of the connected components, which you can then inspect to get their info.

For thresholding you can try [Threshold](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/ref/OpenCVRef_Cv.htm#decl_cvThreshold). I was sure you could pass a flag to it to use Otsu's method, but it doesn't seem to be listed in the docs there.

I haven't come across specific functions corresponding to gray2ind, but they may be in there.

Comment: This is how you use Otsu's method in Threshold: cv.Threshold(src, dst, threshold, maxValue, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY | cv.CV_THRESH_OTSU). The parameter threshold is ignored, since Otsu's method determines the optimal threshold automatically. Doc link: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#Threshold

Answer (score 7):

documentation: A few years ago I used OpenCV wrapped for Python quite a lot.  OpenCV is extensively documented, ships with many examples, and there's even a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130/).  The Python wrappers I was using were thin enough so that very little wrapper specific documentation was required (and this is typical for many other wrapped libraries).  I imagine that a few minutes looking at an example, like the PyCV unit tests would be all you need, and then you could focus on the OpenCV documentation that suited your needs.

analysis: As for whether there's a better library than OpenCV, my somewhat outdated opinion is that OpenCV is great if you want to do fairly advanced stuff (e.g. object tracking), but it is possibly overkill for your needs.  It sounds like scipy [ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html) combined with some basic numpy array manipulation might be enough.

acquisition: The options I know of for acquisition are OpenCV, Motmot, or using ctypes to directly interface to the drivers.  Of these, I've never used Motmot because I had trouble installing it.  The other methods I found fairly straightforward, though I don't remember the details (which is a good thing, since it means it was easy).

Answer (score 4):

I've started a website on this subject: [pythonvision.org](http://pythonvision.org). It has some tutorials, &c and some links to software. There are more links and tutorials there.

Answer (score 2):

You probably would be well served by [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/). Here is the [introductory tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/Getting_Started) for SciPy. It has a lot of similarities to Matlab. Especially the included matplotlib package, which is explicitly made to emulate the Matlab plotting functions. I don't believe SciPy has equivalents for the functions you mentioned. There are some things which are similar. For example, [threshold](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stsci.image.threshhold.html#scipy.stsci.image.threshhold) is a very simple version of graythresh. It doesn't implement "Otsu's" method, it just does a simple threshold, but that might be close enough.

I'm sorry that I don't know of any tutorials which are closer to the task you described. But if you are accustomed to Matlab, and you want to do this in Python, [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this package [Motmot](http://code.astraw.com/projects/motmot/) or how it compares to OpenCV, but I have imported and used a class or two from it.  Much of the image processing is done via numpy arrays and might be similar enough to how you've used Matlab to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've acquired image from FW camera using .NET and  IronPython. On CPython I would checkout ctypes library, unless you find any library support for grabbing.

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: This book is more for people who want a good hands on introduction into computer or machine vision, even though it covers what the original question asked.

### [BOOK]: [**Programming Computer Vision with Python**](http://programmingcomputervision.com/)

At the moment you can download the final draft from the book's website **for free as pdf**:

**http://programmingcomputervision.com/**

From the introduction:

The idea behind this book is to give an easily accessible entry point to hands-on
computer vision with enough understanding of the underlying theory and algorithms
to be a foundation for students, researchers and enthusiasts.

What you need to know

- Basic programming experience. You need to know how to use an editor and run
  scripts, how to structure code as well as basic data types. Familiarity with Python or other scripting style languages like Ruby or Matlab will help.
- Basic mathematics. To make full use of the examples it helps if you know about
  matrices, vectors, matrix multiplication, the standard mathematical functions
  and concepts like derivatives and gradients. Some of the more advanced mathe-
  matical examples can be easily skipped.

What you will learn

- Hands-on programming with images using Python.
- Computer vision techniques behind a wide variety of real-world applications.
- Many of the fundamental algorithms and how to implement and apply them your-
  self.