# Extracting connected objects from an image in Python

Tags: python, image, scipy

I have a graysacle png image and I want to extract all the connected components from my image.
Some of the components have same intensity but I want to assign a unique label to every object.
here is my image

[image]

I tried this code:

```
img = imread(images + 'soccer_cif' + str(i).zfill(6) + '_GT_index.png')
labeled, nr_objects = label(img)
print "Number of objects is %d " % nr_objects
```

But I get just three objects using this.
Please tell me how to get each object.

Comment: Where does the `label` function come from?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5304140/190597

Comment: I am using something similar actually. The label function is from scipy.ndimage 
But getting the result that I posted

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[J.F. Sebastian shows a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5304140/190597) to identify objects in an image. It requires manually choosing a gaussian blur radius and threshold value, however:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname='index.png'
blur_radius = 1.0
threshold = 50

img = Image.open(fname).convert('L')
img = np.asarray(img)
print(img.shape)
# (160, 240)

# smooth the image (to remove small objects)
imgf = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, blur_radius)
threshold = 50

# find connected components
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(imgf > threshold) 
print("Number of objects is {}".format(nr_objects))
# Number of objects is 4 

plt.imsave('/tmp/out.png', labeled)
plt.imshow(labeled)

plt.show()
```

[image]

With `blur_radius = 1.0`, this finds 4 objects.
With `blur_radius = 0.5`, 5 objects are found:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try Gaussian blurring earlier.
This method works better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If the border of objects are completely clear and you have a binary image in img, you can avoid Gaussian filtering and just do this line:

```
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(img)
```