# Otsu's Method and A Median Filter in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I've tried looking around and have been unable to find any implementation of either Otsu's method or a median filter into Python other than OpenCV.These are the only two links of documentation for the OpenCV functions that I've tried.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/image_filtering.html

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/ref/OpenCVRef_Cv.htm#decl_cvThreshold3

I checked this post first but it never really seemed to have a full solution that fits my problem.
[Machine vision in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887252/machine-vision-in-python)

I'm basically looking to see if anyone knows any other functions that I can implement both Otsu's method and a median filter. I'm just trying to find alternatives before I have to program them into myself, but I would rather not have to reinvent the wheel unless necessary. Thanks for your help in advance, if you need some more specific information just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about Otsu's method but the Scipy library has a whole sub-library dedicated to image processing. For example here is the link to their multi-dimensional median filter:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works for the median filter. Now I'm just trying to find a way to perform Otsu's Method in python.

Answer (score 7):

In response to the Otsu Method I was able to find an image processing packaged called Mahotas that contained it. All I had to do was easy_install it. The documentation can be found here.
http://packages.python.org/mahotas/index.html?highlight=otsu#mahotas.otsu

Comment: author of mahotas here: the newest version also includes the median filtering.

Comment: That's for the update :) I don't know how I got by without mahotas before, it has some really convenient functions. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for authoring it and including the otsu filter; tremendously useful and convenient!

Answer (score 0):

The matlab image toolbox includes a built in median filter.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/medfilt2.html

If you don't have the image processing toolbox, you can implement one using block processing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I tagged it as matlab since I'm translating matlab code to python. I untagged it to avoid the confusion. Thanks for your time though :)